# Why does field calculator compute area in square meters?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area

I am using *EPSG:102748*, and have set my Settings/Option preferred measurement units to ft.  My CRS is *NAD_1983_StatePlane_Washington_North_FIPS_4601_Feet*, and when I use the measure tool, it returns the area in square ft or square miles or acres.  When I use the field calculator to compute an area field, I am just entering the `$area` function.  It is returning square meters instead of square feet.

Comment: That is unusual, have you tried calculate geometry instead?

Comment: If the issue is  reproducible, please open a bug report to inform the devs of this issue.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with that code not appearing to be a valid EPSG id, but rather an Esri SRID (as [discussed here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91361/esri-projection-to-srid/91370#91370))?

Comment: After playing with it, I am able to get the right answer, but there is definitely something I'm not understanding as it appears that the sequence of steps used to derive the areas has something to do with it.  Perhaps it has something to do with the project projection and the projection of the separate layers.  In any case.  Thanks for the suggestions and support.  I would have to say it is user error/learning.

Comment: Two things immediately come to mind. First, as mentioned earlier, if QGIS is not recognizing that code as the appropriate projection and therefore applying an incorrect projection and/or transformation to either the layer or project. Second, per [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21691/), have you enabled on-the-fly projection? My understanding is that in QGIS that doesn't always work as smoothly as in ArcGIS - sometimes you actually need to reproject the data rather than just do it on the fly to get correct results. May also be a tool setting - use project or layer CRS.

Comment: Another possibility in Andre's answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136392/ which seems to note that some internal tools or calculations don't use the correct units.