# USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic to miles

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-2, united-states

My data is in USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic projection. How can I convert the USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic projection to miles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a custom CRS with miles as units, like

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=33 +lat_2=45 +lat_0=39 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=mi +no_defs
```

Then save your data to that CRS and turn on-the-fly-reprojection **OFF**.

Unfortunately, the distance tools still writes `km` as unit, but the USA is about 2886 miles wide, while it is 4649 km in the original lcc projection. This will be changeable in the upcoming new QGIS 2.8.

You need a recent version of QGIS, because older versions did not treat units other than meters and feet correctly.

Comment: Thank you Andrej for the response. Am just curious whether QGIS -> Settings -> Custom CRS is the way for creating custom crs?

Comment: Yes, that's the right way. You can copy the standard projection string from project or layer settings, and edit that.